# How can you use face recognition on raspberry pi as a login to the pi?

Tags: camera, opencv, security

I have created an owncloud server using RPI, Now I was wondering how to implement the face recognition as a login for the pi.
I know I have to use the OpenCV.

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point would be [pam-face-authentication](https://code.google.com/p/pam-face-authentication/). From there site:

> PAM Face Authentication is a pluggable authentication module designed for facial authentication. You can use this module for any service that requires authentication, internally handled by the PAM library.

To get started you would need to [compile from source](https://code.google.com/p/pam-face-authentication/wiki/WikiInstallationFromSource) as it is not available as a .deb in apt.

Answer (score 2):

Try developing a small opencv program that detects certain faces or shapes and then use it as a login screen (see SLiM) at system startup (could use it as a wrapper for one of those login managers).

I am not sure if there is a project already that deals with this on linux systems, but developing one one seems useful on any linux distro for those interested.

Comment: do you mean slim framework?  When you say system start up you mean for the raspberry pi right? not for the actual cloud start up.

Comment: @user10826 sorry for the extremely late response, no, i meant SLiM (now abandoned) Https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM Again, I pointed to this only to show an example of an easy lightweight login manager.